# how not to load fixtures into the database?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, fixtures

I have to load some fixtures in my symfony1 database, but they depend on data which is already stored. The problem is that if I dump the dependent data, in order to complete my yml file, it will be reinserted into the database, and this is the thing I want to avoid.

Do you know any trick to do this ?

Comment: I think some more details are needed here. How are you inserting the fixtures into the database? If you have a dump of your data can't you just import the dump instead of using the fixtures?

Comment: I have a table named Service and antoher named Employee. An employee can be affected to many Services. My Service table is already containing the needed data. I am writing the yml file in order to insert my employees into the Employee table.

Comment: So you have a yml file with the employees. I'm still not sure what's your problem here.

Comment: The problem is that I want to set the Services field for each Employee, which will link an Employee to many services, but to do this, I would have to recreate my Service fixtures so I can use them in my Employee's Services field ; doing this would re-insert the Service fixtures, which I want to avoid.

Comment: I don't think you need to do this. Can you post parts of the fixtures files you are using (for the employees and for the match).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what I want. I had to dump my existing tables, then edit my yml to make it corresponding to the dumped data, then reload everything.

Answer (score 0):

I only know it for Propel, there is a task append:

```
./symfony propel:data-load --append
```

The append task will not empty your database, but will append the fixture data to the tables.

Comment: quid of inserting the data already present, won't be the data present twice